# Find corner of field

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am working on project in C#/Emgu CV, but answer in any language with OpenCv should be ok.

I have following image: http://i42.tinypic.com/2z89h5g.jpg
Or it might look like this: http://i43.tinypic.com/122iwsk.jpg

I am trying to do automatic calibration and I would like to know how to find corners of the field. They are marked by LEDs, but I would prefer to find it by color tags. If need I can replace all tags by same color tags. (Note that light in room is changing so the colors might be bit different next time)

Edge detection might be ok too, but I am afraid that I would not find the corner correctly.

Please help.
Thank you.

**Edit:**

Thanks aardvarkk for advice, but I think I need to give you little bit more info.
I am already able to detect and identify robots in field and get their position and rotation. But for that I have to set corners of field manually first. So I was looking for aa automatic way, but I was worried I would not be able to distinguish color tags from background because light in the room is changing quite often.

And as for the camera angle. Point of this is that camera can be every time from different (reasonable) angle.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by searching for the colours. The LEDs won't be much help to you as they're not much brighter than anything else in the scene. I would look for the rectangular pieces of coloured tape. Try segmenting the image based on colour. That may allow you to retrieve the corner tape pieces directly without needing to know their exact colour in advance. After that, you may look for pairs of the same colour blob that are close to each other to define the corners where the pieces of tape are the same. Knowing what kinds of camera angles you are going to have to solve is also very important -- if you need this to work when viewing from the side, then this approach certainly won't work. If it's almost top down, this would probably be a good start. Nobody will be able to provide you with a start to finish solution, but this might be a good base to begin with.